Proving $(′(_1))^2+(′(_2))^2=2 $for $$ such that $()=$ and $()=$
Let $f$ be continuous on $[,]$ and differentiable on $(,)$. 
If $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$, show that there exist distinct $c_1, c_2 \in (,)$
such that $$(′(_1))^2+(′(_2))^2=2$$

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

The header question doesn't exactly match the question in the body.  The one in the body seems obviously wrong, so I assume the header question is the one you intended?

Hint:  argue that, if the function isn't $f(x)=x$, then there must be a point $c\in (a,b)$ with $f'(c)>1$.  That's enough.

Sorry but I didn't find the hint quite helpful for me. Is it possible that $f'$ isn't continuous, and there is only one point where $f'>1$?

Whether $f'$ is continuous or not is immaterial. What matters is that derivatives satisfy intermediate value property and that's sufficient to get to the desired conclusion.
